# Dangers of not using await

Tags: c#, .net-core

To enhance performance, I want to exit a function without waiting for all async functions to complete. I only care about the results of the first function. The others should complete when ever and log their own exceptions.

```
// I care about this result
int? bookingId = await BookingService.SaveBooking(...); 

// These should run async in the background. All async methods.
EmailService.SendEmail(...);
CreditCardService.SaveCard(...);
SMSService.SendSms(...);

return bookingId;
```

What are the risks of omitting *await* keyword there?

Comment: I actually have read about async programming, but I couldn't really find an answer for this. Also Visual Studio gives a warning, which causes me to think I'm probably doing something wrong. Also, read this: https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/

Comment: Well, if you don´t want to use async, than don´t do it. What is the point here?

Comment: Just take care where your exceptions are going and what actions are going on at the same time (email/creditcard/sms most likely happens all at the same time).

Comment: @HimBromBeere Maybe some possibility of memory leaking if the other functions throw exceptions or are not exited correctly?

Comment: it isn't clear from the names; are `SendEmail`, `SaveCard`, `SendSms` etc also async methods? and are they *actually* async? something can return `Task<T>` and be named `FooAsync`, but still be implemented synchronously...

Comment: @judehall what do you want, someone to write a answer saying "no" ? You lack fundamental knowledge, and SO isn't the place to get that. If you expect someone to write a 10000 word article as an answer explaining how asynchronous programming works, you have gravely misunderstood the purpose of SO. You need to go back to basic, and learn the difference between synchronous and asynchronous programming.

Comment: @ClausJørgensen, if everybody has fundamental knowledge as you suggest, then SO wouldn't be so popular ;)

Comment: @Fabio regardless, SO is for questions that can be directly answered, not giving advice on fundamentals. OP's question does not apply here. This is well documented in the "how to ask questions". OP attempting to use the new Code of Conduct as an excuse for asking a terrible question like this shouldn't be allowed at all.

Answer (score 3):

The main risk here is that they fail and cause unobserved exceptions. A secondary risk is that they attempt to interact with some async state that no longer makes sense once the main operation has completed. If you're happy that neither of these things are a problem, you should be fine - but you should be a little cautious with this approach. This is essentially a "fire and forget" scenario - the compiler will try to fight you